A distribution defined via an ODE for its Laplace trnsform
Fix a parameter $0 < c < \infty$.
As the solution to a certain problem,
there is a probability density function $f_c(t)$ on $0 < t < \infty$ with mean $1$ and
whose Laplace transform $L(\theta)$ satisfies the ODE
$ L^2(\theta) - (2 + \theta c) L(\theta) 
- c \theta L^\prime (\theta) 
+ 1 = 0$
with $L(0) =1, \  L^\prime(0) = -1$.
From the background story, we know qualitatively that the corresponding distribution concentrates around $1$ for large $c$ and becomes spread out for small $c$.
Can we obtain anything more explicit about $f_c$?

That's a Riccati equation, and it has a known (if complicated) general solution.  However, Wolfram Alpha tells me no solution with that $L'(0)$ exists.

You are trying to impose two initial conditions. Is $L^2$ supposed to mean the second derivative rather than the square of $L^2$?

L^2 is the square of L
